# Corrupted Rmarkdown script: How can I get the Cyrillic characters back?

Tags: r, nlp, rstudio, r-markdown

I was working with a script with lots of Cyrillic characters (throughout chunks and out of them) for weeks. One day I have opened a new Rmarkdown script where I wrote English, while the other document is still in my R session. Afterwards, I have returned to the Cyrillic document and everything written turns to something like this `8 Ð¸ÑÐ»ÑÂ 1995 --> ÐÐ»Ð°ÑÑÑ - Ð½Ð°ÑÐ¾Ð´Ñ`

**The question is**: Where is the source of problem? And, how can the corrupted script turn to its original form (with the Cyrillic characters)?

---

**UPDATE!!**

I have tried reopeining the Rstudio scrip with encoding CP1251, CP1252, windows1251 and UTF8, but it does not work. Certaintly the weird symbols change to another weird symbols. The problem is that I have saved the document with the default encoding CP1251 and windows1251) at the very begining.

---

**Solution:**
If working with cyrillic and lating characters, be sure you save the Rstudio script with UTF-8 encoding always, when you computer is windows (I do not know mac). If you close the script and open it again, re-open the file with UTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using RStudio: Open your *.Rmd file and then try to reopen it "with encoding". Therefore simply use the File-Menu as shown below.

[image]

Select "Show all encodings" and choose your specific encoding, I suggest *windows-1251* for cyrillic encoding:

[image]

*Note:* Apparently the issue can also occur while at the one time opening the *.Rmd file as "standalone" and at the other time from within an R Project.

Hope that would help.

Comment: I was about to update the post, @jaySf  because I have tried that + CP1251 and UTF8. It does not work, but certaintly the weird symbols change to another weird symbols :´( Perhaps the problem is that I have saved the document with the default encoding

Comment: @adrian-del-rio-rodriguez Bad thing, perhaps it's worth checking out [this decoder](https://2cyr.com/decode/)?

Comment: Yes, it Works for some cases. I guess the problem is that I have to save the script as UTF-8 (no CP-1251, OR Windows1252) at the very beggining and be sure is always like that. This is how I have avoided the problem again. Also I have saved the codes as a .csv file

Comment: Happy to hear that and that you have found a way to avoid the issue in future!